# [NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nstimeinterval

I would like to compare difference between two dates, but with the code below I got the error "[NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance." What's wrong with the code?

```
NSDate *dateAdded=[eventDictionary objectForKey:@"dateAdded"];
NSDate *validUntilDate=[eventDictionary objectForKey:@"validUntilDate"];
NSDateComponents *sometimeAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:dateAdded  toDate:validUntilDate  options:0];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `dateAdded` and/or `validUntilDate` are actually strings and not dates. Maybe they are strings representing dates, but strings after all.

Comment: You could try to avoid it with `NSDate* dateAdded=(NSDate*)[eventDictionary objectForKey:@"dateAdded"];`

Comment: If the object returned by `objectForKey:` is not a `NSDate`, a cast won't make it become one.

Comment: Not? In case the original variable for the key "dateAdded" is a NSDate* it should be returning a NSDate*. Or am I wrong?

Comment: If the value for the key "dateAdded" is a `NSDate` it will return a `NSDate` and you don't need the cast. If it is not a `NSDate`, the cast won't help.

Comment: That's true. So I guess you will be right with your assumption.

Comment: it comes in Float value! enclosed in inverted commas, So that is why typcast do nothing :( By the way any solution/workaround ?????

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your date strings to actual NSDates.

Comment: If there are lot of dates, it unnecessarily impacts the performance